# Matlab installer runs out of space

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Matlab using Arch linux via the official install script. Everything works perfectly fine and the download starts after selecting all components. Now the problem is that apparently the installer puts the downloaded content into /tmp, which I have assigned 4gb (half of my ram). This has never been a problem until now. About at 25% of the installation/download the installer raises an error, saying that there is no more space left in /tmp.
I checked the directory before starting the installation and it had 4gb free space.

Can I redirect a different directory to the installer where there is plenty of space, because there is plenty of it free on the drive ? The installer asked for installation directory but didn't give me the option to select this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Why are you setting `/tmp` to "half of your ram"? Are you confusing it with _swap space_? That said, have you got enough space in your `/` partition?

Comment: If the installer honors the `TMPDIR` environment variable, you could set this to the path of a directory that has more space. Since I don't use Matlab, I can't say whether this would work or not.

Comment: Thank you! I actually cannot really remember back to when I did this I'm afraid. When using `df` I saw that i mounted `/` to `/dev/sda2` which has 400+ gb of free space.

Comment: @Kusalananda I searched the install script for such a variable but did not find anything sadly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the installer doesn't honor the `TMP` or `TMPDIR` environment variables, as @thrig pointed out in their answer, and the `/tmp` partition / ramdisk by itself is too small, then simply mount something else on it:

```
mkdir "$HOME/matlabdl"
mount --bind -o nonempty "$HOME/matlabdl" /tmp
```

Contrary to a normal mount, a `--bind` mount takes an existing directory and mounts it at a different place, i.e. instead of downloading into the ramdisk that normally is at `/tmp` the download actually goes into `$HOME/matlabdl` in this case. `-o nonempty` makes sure that the mount takes place even if `/tmp` is not empty, as would normally be required.

After the installation completes, unmount /tmp again:

```
umount /tmp
```

This will make the ramdisk visible again. In case some process is still using your overridden `/tmp`, look for which one it is with tools like `lsof`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Also nice explanations, I didn't know about `--bind`

Answer (score 1):

The installer in `matlab_R2018b_glnxa64.zip` ignores `TMP` and ignores `TMPDIR`, instead using `/tmp` directly. The full download runs to 9597 MB, and 27 GB after installation. One method would be to work through the installer multiple times and only install a subset of the sets so that `/tmp` use never goes above your limit. Another is to use a `LD_PRELOAD` trick to make it write somewhere else. Yet another way is to pause the download from the install GUI after it has started, and then:

```
% cd /tmp
% ls | grep -v systemd
hsperfdata_jhqdoe
mathworks_24989
mathworks_jhqdoe.log
mathworks_jhqdoe.log.lck
tmw1537542523097
% mv tmw1537542523097 /some/where/with/space
% ln -s /some/where/with/space tmw1537542523097
```

and then unpause the installer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "LD_PRELOAD" trick ? How would one go about that ? also is there a reason for that ? is my /tmp folder supposed to be that large ?

Comment: search for `LD_PRELOAD` articles. it requires compiling a special library and then monkey patching that into the MATLAB install process

Comment: Simply moving it around like that will not work, as /some/where/with/space is no longer on the /tmp filesystem, which means your `mv` actually is a `cp` + `rm` - the installer will keep downloading the file(s) into /tmp, possibly failing later because it can't find them anymore.